# Enable local development access to PostgreSQL DB on Amazon RDS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc

I'm in the early stages of a web project which requires a database. Until now, I've managed to get away with using an SQLite database locally for development and a PostgreSQL database running on AWS RDS in "production" (mainly just for alpha testers). I haven't really had any state in the database that I couldn't just blow away and re-seed whenever necessary.

However, I'm now at the point in my project where I'm going to have state in the production database that I can't easily reproduce via seeding in my local SQLite database. So I've decided to create another development database that I create via a script which just takes the last snapshot of my production database and creates a production database. I've managed to get this script running with some degree of success...

But I'm having difficulty connecting to this development database in my local development environment. Each time I try to connect, I timeout. Most of the resources on Amazon seem to indicate that this is likely a security group issue. The security group corresponding to my database currently has these inbound settings (security group erased, but it is the group listed as my RDS security group):

[image]

Is there something obviously wrong here? How do I set up my security groups such that I can connect to this development database on my local machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source shouldn't be set to the same security group, but rather whatever source you'll be connecting from. You can use 0.0.0.0/0 to enable traffic from any source.